# Simulating Pause/Play on apps such as YouTube from a service

Tags: java, android, android-studio, service, android-audiomanager

I am trying to simulate the Play/Pause actions globally so that if a YouTube video is playing, it would pause or resume.

I am unsure of how to implement this specifically in a service.

So I have this function

```
public static void sendMediaButton(Context context, int keyCode) {
    KeyEvent keyEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyCode);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, keyEvent);
    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);

    keyEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyCode);
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, keyEvent);
    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
}
```

and I call it like

```
sendMediaButton(getApplicationContext(), KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE);
```

However in my service, that doesn't do anything, the YouTube video is still playing.

FWIW, my app has both `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` and `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permissions so it can still start Activities and whatnot with minimal restrictions..

My question is: how do I go about emulating play and pause actions within my service?

Thanks!